# Can the Auto Number display format reset for each new year

Tags: administration, auto-number

I have created an Auto Number with the following format: `{YYYY}/{000}`.

Is it possible for the number increments `{000}` to reset to 1 for each new year?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to reset the number but it needs to be done manually for each auto-number field. [This help article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005195&language=en_US) explains it.

> This can be accomplished with the following steps:
>
> 1: Click on:
>
> Setup | App Setup | Customize | Object name | Fields | Edit Field Name
>   | Click the Change Type of this Field button.
>
> 2: Change the field type to Text, click Next, click Save.
>
> 3: Repeat the steps noted above and change the field type back to Auto Number , this allows you to set the starting auto-number.
>
> You will receive a caution warning that if the next number you enter
>   is not higher than existing numbers, it may be possible to create
>   records with duplicate numbers when changing the auto-number format
>   multiple times using similar formats.
>
> **Note:** This does not work for objects installed by managed released packages, as components below are locked:
>   - "data type" on custom field
>   - "record name data type" on custom object
>   - "record name display format" on custom object
>
> - If you want to restart auto number fields on objects from a managed released package, you can uninstall the package and reinstall it.